# HTTP authentication with PHP for specific pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, authentication

I have been trying to fix one issue for the last two weeks but didn't find any solution to my problem. So, I am trying to add HTTP authentication with PHP 7.4.

**The main issue**

I have to add restrictions for specific URLs ( For example, https://example.com/photos ) with PHP, and I am using the below code. But the problem is I have to show logged-in users on other pages, too. For example, if I didn't log in, then anything to show, but if I am logged in need to show username and password on all pages, but again I have to restrict only specific pages.

**PHP Code:**

```
Header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm='Members Only' valid-user");
http_response_code(401);
echo "<script> window.location.replace( 'https://example.com/sign-up' ) </script>";
exit;
```

**.htaccess Code:**

```
AuthUserfile PATH_TO_THE_FILE/.htpasswd
AuthName "Members Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
```

I hope someone will help me soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

Put these 2 files in a folder...change the password fields and the refresh redirect code once correct password is entered.

index.php

```
    <meta name='robots' content='noindex, nofollow' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=1">

<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit_pass']) && $_POST['pass'])
{
 $pass=$_POST['pass'];
 if($pass=="12345678")
 {
  $_SESSION['password']=$pass;
 }
 else
 {
  $error="Incorrect Pssword";
 }
}

if(isset($_POST['page_logout']))
{
 unset($_SESSION['password']);
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="password_style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<?php
if($_SESSION['password']=="12345678")
{
 ?>
 
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://example.com">

 <?php
}
else
{
 ?>
 <form method="post" action="" id="login_form">
  <h1>LOGIN TO PROCEED</h1>
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="*******">
  <input type="submit" name="submit_pass" value="SUBMIT">
  <p><font style="color:red;"><?php echo $error;?></font></p>
 </form>
 <?php  
}
?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

password_style.css

```
body
{
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0px;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 font-family: "Myriad Pro","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif;
 background-color:#8A4B08;
}
#wrapper
{
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0px;
 text-align:center;
 width:995px;
}
#wrapper h1
{
 margin-top:50px;
 font-size:45px;
 color:white;
}
#wrapper p
{
 font-size:16px;
}
#logout_form input[type="submit"]
{
 width:250px;
 margin-top:10px;
 height:40px;
 font-size:16px;
 background:none;
 border:2px solid white;
 color:white;
}
#login_form
{
 margin-top:200px;
 background-color:white;
 width:350px;
 margin-left:310px;
 padding:20px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px #3B240B;
}
#login_form h1
{
 margin:0px;
 font-size:25px;
 color:#8A4B08;
}
#login_form input[type="password"]
{
 width:250px;
 margin-top:10px;
 height:40px;
 padding-left:10px;
 font-size:16px;
}
#login_form input[type="submit"]
{
 width:250px;
 margin-top:10px;
 height:40px;
 font-size:16px;
 background-color:#8A4B08;
 border:none;
 box-shadow:0px 4px 0px 0px #61380B;
 color:white;
 border-radius:3px;
}
#login_form p
{
 margin:0px;
 margin-top:15px;
 color:#8A4B08;
 font-size:17px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to login with AuthBasicProvider file

Comment: Not sure you understand or not but i am talking about HTTP authentication

Comment: in the .htpasswd file you need to add the username/password to access the page. Go here to create the passwords for doing this. https://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator

Comment: Heres more to look at. https://www.wmtips.com/php/simple-ways-restrict-access-webpages-using/ good examples that do the trick.

Comment: i already have username/passwords in my /htpasswd file, but the is i am not able to show logged in user on other pages after login

Comment: You have to create php sessions and add the code to all other pages.

Comment: yes i am already using session but without Require valid-user this code u am not able to do it